# Relationship between the size of a set, size of an equivalence relation on that set, and the number of equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

I'm having trouble with this question on my discrete math HW:

Let R be an equivalence relation defined on a finite set A, such that |A| = n and
|R|= m. Let k be the number of equivalence classes of R.

Prove that $n^2 \le km$

The professor gave the hit to use the Cauchy-Shwarz Inequality:
$(\sum_{i=1}^px_iy_i)^2 \le (\sum_{i=1}^px_i^2)(\sum_{i=1}^py_i^2)$

My initial thought process was to try to represent |A| as $\sum_{i=1}^px_iy_i$, |R| as $\sum_{i=1}^px_i^2$ and k or the # of equivalence classes as $\sum_{i=1}^py_i^2$ but I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: Hint: suppose you know the sizes of all the equivalence classes. How would you compute $|R|$?

Comment: @Karl Ok so I played around with some relations and found that if $x_i$ is the size of equivalence class i then $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i^2 = |R| = m$ (really not sure how to prove that though). Then equivalence classes are pairwise disjoint and union to A, $\sum_{i=1}^k x_i = |A| = n$. I figured I could also write k as $\sum_{i=1}^k y_i^2$ where $y_i = 1$. In that same vein $n^2 = (\sum_{i=1}^k x_iy_i)^2$ which gets me to the inequality in my professors hint, and thus proves the statement $n^2 \le km$. I need to just figure out how to prove the initial statement relating size of the classes and |R|

Comment: Nice! Interesting that you arrived at that statement without discovering a proof of it. Remember that the relation $R$ is a set of *pairs* of elements of $A$. What can you say about the pairs in an equivalence relation (and how they relate to the equivalence classes)? How do the classes determine the pairs?

Comment: (And how does squaring a number relate to counting pairs of objects? Can you view $x^2$ as an application of the [multiplication principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product)?)

Comment: @Karl I was able to come up with a coherent complete proof. Thank you!